# Trigger a jQuery custom event set by different instance

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there any way to trigger custom events set by a different jQuery instance?  For example:

```
// Load version 1.9.1
...
jQuery191(document).on('customEvent', function () {console.log('Callback fired.')});

// Load version 1.6.2 and setup noConflict
...
jQuery162(document).trigger('customEvent');
```

While it's not [recommended](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/) to load more than one version of the library, a simple use-case is a plugin that pulls in a specific version of jQuery if the current instance is lower than expected.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried it? I can't see why it wouldn't work, although as you say it's not ideal to be using two different versions of jQuery.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan custom events are not real events and handled by using the internal data stored by jQuery. Because every jQuery instance has its own `jQuery.expando` used for the internal data. Event handlers are completely isolated between different instances, even if they are of the same version.

Comment: @t.niese Good point. Consider me schooled.

Comment: @t.niese Is there another manner in which I can create custom events and listen to/trigger them?  I have a solution (using Event and CustomEvent) that works for webkit and firefox but not the dreaded IE.

Comment: @stavarotti I'm working on an answer (but it's not something i would recommend, but it's up to you if you want to use it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should really take care if you have different instance (even if the same version) on a page, because this could lead to unexpected behavior and could result in memory leaks, e.g. if you remove an element with `jQuery191` that has data (`.data(...)` or event listeners) that was stored with `jQuery162` this will remain in memory until you reload the page and the other way round.

But back to your question.
I would not recommend it but you could double the event (trigger it with both versions).
The problem with this approach is that it would slow down everything.
And the other problem is that you have two bubbling phases. So if you prevent the event in `jQuery191`  it will still be executed in `jQuery162` and the other way round.

So it could be a solution that works for you, but it could also make the things worser.
So you need to check your self if this solution is something you can use.
Probably you also can remove one of the doubling parts.

```
(function() {
    //keep the original functions
    var trigger191 = jQuery191.fn.trigger;
    var trigger162 = jQuery162.fn.trigger;

    jQuery191.fn.trigger = function( evt ) {
        trigger191.apply(this,arguments); //call orginal function

        //only double certain events
        if( evt == "my-custom-event" ) {
            var resultset162 = jQuery162(jQuery191.makeArray( this ));//create a ne result set of the 162 version
            trigger162.apply(resultset162,arguments); //call the original function of 162 to avoid an endless loop
        }
    };

    jQuery162.fn.trigger = function(evt) {
        trigger162.apply(this,arguments); //call orginal function

        //only double certain events
        if( evt == "my-custom-event" ) {
            var resultset191 = jQuery191(trigger162.makeArray( this ));
            trigger191.apply(resultset191,arguments); //call the ofiginal function of 191 to avoid an endless loop
        }
    };

})();
```

(I hope the code works that way. I pretty sure it should work, but I can't test it right now)

Comment: This seems to fit my original line of thinking.  I need to do some testing to figure out performance penalties.